# Процесс загрузки через fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
fetch('/jx/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: FormAdd({md:'uploads', fix:vl.key, id:vl.id, t:vl.t, file:e.target.files[0]})
}).then(
    r => r.json() // if the response is a JSON object
  ).then(s => eval(s));
```

Работает, файлы загружаются. Как к данному коду добавить возможность слушать, то сколько байт передано. То есть узнать процент загруженного?

Comment: [Тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-progress) почитай

Comment: Как в таком случаи файл с параметрами отправить? Что не пробую, одни ошибки...

Comment: что тут имеется ввиду под "загрузкой"? Отправка файла на сервер? Или скачивание файла на клиент?

Comment: Отправка на сервер

Comment: fetch не поодерживает progress для upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` не предоставляет такого функционала. Он может показывать прогресс для ЗАГРУЗКИ, но не для ВЫГРУЗКИ. Вы не можете это организовать с помощью только JS в браузере.

см. похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch